# How to append a string to only consonants in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Right now I'm trying to create an oppish translator. That is, after a consonant or several consonants in a row, you add 'op' to those letters. As an example, cow would become copowop or street which would become stropeetop. This is what I have so far:

```
def oppish(phrase): #with this function I'm going to append 'op' or 'Op' to a string.
    consonants =  ['b','c','d','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z']
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] #this and the preceding line create a variable for the vowels we will be looking to append 'op' to.    
    if phrase == '':    #error case. if the input is nothing then the program will return False.
        return False
    phrase_List = list(' ' + phrase) # turns the input phrase into a list which allows for an        index to search for consonants later on.
    new_phrase_List = list() #creates new list for oppish translation
    for i in range(1, len(phrase_List)):
        if phrase_List[i] == phrase_List[1]:
            new_phrase_List.append(phrase_List[i])
        elif phrase_List[i] in consonants:
            new_phrase_List.append('op') #adds op to the end of a consonant within the list and then appends it to the newlist
        new_phrase_List.append(phrase_List[i]) #if the indexed letter is not a consonant it is appended to the new_phrase_list.
    print 'Translation: ' + ''.join(new_phrase_List)

oppish('street')
```

The only problem here is that the above code yields this

```
Translation: ssoptopreeopt
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong, I've tried going through a visualizer but to no avail. All help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Well for one you have `i` in your consonants list

Comment: How do you mean? Shouldn't I be using 'i' to index check consonants and then append them to the new list I've created?

Comment: @JohnathanScott: `'i'` is the string `i`. It has no relation to your `i` variable. What do you expect `phrase_List[i] == phrase_List[1]` to do?

Comment: It's not affecting this particular use case but I'm saying you have the letter `'i'` in your consonants list and in your vowel list. Not to be confused with your index variable `i`.

Comment: Also, I think your translation is backwards. You should be doing `consonant => consonant` and `vowel => 'op' + vowel`.

Comment: Ah I see. So if I append op + 'vowel' to the list instead it would come up properly! Duh, can't believe I didn't think of that. And thanks for noticing the 'i' in consonants, ill change that.

Comment: So I've removed the first if statement 'phrase_List[i] == phrase_List[1]' and changed 'if phrase_List[i] in consonants' to 'if phrase_List[i] in vowels' With that I'm getting stropeopet. Not quite sure what to do now...

Comment: (small) lists are OK for membership testing, but that's what sets are for really.

Comment: It's also a lot less typing to say `vowels = list("aeiou")` or even just `vowels='aeiou'` if you are iterating through them.

Answer (score 2):

This is well suited for [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), which will let you group items in an iterable using a key function. The group will accumulate until the return value of the key function changes, at which point `group` by will yield return value of the key function and an iterator over the accumulated group. In this case, we want our key function to return `True` if a letter is a vowel. That way, we'll get groups of consecutive consonants, and groups of consecutive vowels back from `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}  # set instead of list, because lookups are O(1)

def oppish(phrase):
    if not phrase:
        return False

    out  = []
    for is_vowel, letters in groupby(phrase, lambda x: x in vowels):
        out.append(''.join(list(letters)))
        if not is_vowel:
            out.append('op')
    return ''.join(out)


print oppish('street')
print oppish('cow')
```

Output:

```
stropeetop
copowop
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your approach to the problem. 
Try to do something like this:

EDIT: Although there's a better (pythonic) answer in this question (thanks to dano), this one does not require additional libraries

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

def oppish(word):
    result = []
    first = True
    prev_vowel = False

    for letter in list(word):
        if (letter in vowels) and (not first) and (not prev_vowel):
            result.append('op')
            prev_vowel = True
        else:
            prev_vowel = False

        result.append(letter)
        first = False
        if not prev_vowel:
            result.append('op')
        print ''.join(result)


oppish('street')

#> stropeetop
```

TIP: Don't waste your time defining both vowels and consonants. in fact, there are vowels and non-vowels